# EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/runner/work/gos_front/gos_front/node_modules/.yarn-integrity

Tags: github, continuous-integration, cypress

I have this workflow.yaml for github actions:

```
name: CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: install --ignore-engines

      - name: Run linters
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: lint:prettier

      - name: Run cypress
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm start

      - name: Build
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: build
```

Then it runs, on `run cypress` occurs an error:

> error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, unlink
> '/home/runner/work/gos_front/gos_front/node_modules/.yarn-integrity'"

.

Before that I add `cypress run` all was right. I tried to add `sudo` but it not helped. I use yarn.

Answer (score 0):

`cypress-io/github-action` tries to install dependencies as well and runs into an access issue. The problem is the way your `node_modules` folder is created.

I ran into this when using Docker, mapping `node_modules` from inside the docker image to the outside. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1317).

You use `borales/actions-yarn`. This is an outdated package, that probably does something similar. You should instead use yarn directly. From their readme:

> Please keep in mind that this Action was originally written for GitHub Actions beta (when Docker was the only way of doing things). Consider using actions/setup-node to work with Yarn. This repository will be mostly supporting the existing flows.